# Замена тегов при XInclude

Tags: xml

Есть два xml-я.

a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
   <host>
       <xi:include href="b.xml" xpointer="xpointer(/b/url/text())"/>
   </host>
</a>
```

b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<b>
   <url>http://ya.ru</url>
   <url>http://google.ru</url>
</b>
```

Сейчас после xinclude a.xml превращается в:

```
<a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
   <host>
       http://ya.ruhttp://google.ru
   </host>
</a>
```

А хотелось бы:

```
<a xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
   <host>
       http://ya.ru
   </host>
   <host>
      http://google.ru
   </host>
</a>
```

Как это сделать?